# From pandas dataframe to dataframe with n-dimensional array as feature

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataset that logs user activity with a learning platform (the OULAD). The dataset has a row for every time a user clicks in the platform somewhere

| user_id | date | sum_clicks | class |

I am trying to take that dataframe and make, for every user_id an n-dimensional vector with each member being the number of clicks on that day, on which I will then perform logistic regression to try and predict class based on platform interaction. I'm sure I could brute for it, but it feels like there should be a 'pandas'/numpy way of doing this. Does anyone have some insight as to the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use pandas groupby data by user_id and date. Then from sklearn use logistic regression as show here: https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-logistic-regression-in-python-step-by-step-becd4d56c9c8

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded by using .pivot_table

```
df.pivot_table(values='sum_click', index=df.user_id, columns='date')
```